# Ethernet over GRE

Tags: 12.04, networking

I'm looking at configuring *Ethernet over GRE* on Ubuntu and have not come across any resources on it yet.

This talks about configuring *IP over GRE*, I believe.

```
http://onvox.net/linux/how-to-create-ipv4-gre-tunnels-in-ubuntu
```

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps solved my problem; posting it here for others' benefit:

```
#sudo ip link add gt0 type gretap remote <IP> local <IP> [csum] [seq]
#sudo ip addr add <IP/mask> dev gt0
#sudo ip link set gt0 up
```

The same needs to be done on the other end with the appropriate values.